# laravel how to use serviceprovider in job

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I have a service provider app/Providers/MailchimpServiceProvider.php.
I have added it to providers in config/app.php

Now I would like to use it in a Job:

```
class SendMail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Mailchimp $mailchimp)
    {
        dd($mailchimp);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
    }
}
```

I think the DI only works in the controllers. How would I use the mailchimp singleton within the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject your dependencies in the `handle` method:

```
public function handle(Mailchimp $mailchimp)
{

}
```